# PHPMailer Extension missing: openssl

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl, phpmailer

Based on the example that PHPMailer provides I have this script:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $patrimonio = $_POST['patrimonio'];
    $serial = $_POST['serial'];
    $unidade=$_POST['unidade'];
    $endereco=$_POST['endereco'];
    $setor=$_POST['setor'];
    $telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
    $procedencia=$_POST['procedencia'];
    $equipamento=$_POST['equipamento'];    
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = gethostbyname("smtp.gmail.com");
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypass";
$mail->setFrom("myemail@gmail.com", 'Gerador de OS');
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);
$mail->AddBCC('HelpDesk@gmail.com', $name);
$mail->Subject = "Abertura de OS";
$mail->Body=$message;
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "true";
}
}
```

Even if that is the exactly the same as the original example, I cannot get it to work.

The error that I get is:

```
Extension missing: openssl
Mailer Error: Extension missing: openssl
```

But the server said everything is ok with the command below:

```
php -i | grep -i openssl
```

and the result was:

```
openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled

OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012 

OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012 Native 

OpenSSL support => enabled
```

There are joomla in this server and I can confirm that OpenSSL is running.

[Joomla informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJPCq.png)

[More joom informations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4NXf.png)

Comment: `php -i` only shows you the PHP CLI SAPI. You need to run `phpinfo()` via your web server to see if it has different options.

Comment: Synchro, the phpinfo() show same information about the openssl...

Comment: IIRC, PHPMailer checks for the existence of openssl by checking constants rather than the ext itself (for safe mode issues) - it looks like you’re using a very old openssl version which may not include the necessary constant.

Comment: Synchro, Would you recommend some Openssl version?

Answer (score 0):

On PHP 7 uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` in the php.ini file around line 921. Also check that `extension=php_openssl.dll` is uncommented lower down around line 1945.